# How do I disconnect code generated by a T4 template from that template?

Tags: visual-studio, t4, visual-studio-2012

When I 'run' a T4 template, the class files it generates for me all appear under the template.  I cannot remove the template from the project without the files going away too. I also can't copy the files out from 'under' the template into the project root because the are already in the project root. How can I emancipate these files from the template that created them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get creative:

1. Right click and open containing folder.
2. Drag-and-drop the generated file to another location in the solution.
3. Delete the original template and file from Visual Studio.
4. Presto.

Comment: Nice, but it's annoying we have to around this.

Comment: The answer above is reasonable, or you can disconnect them by editing the project file - it should be pretty obvious if you search for the .tt file and the generated file - just remove the attributes that connect them.

Comment: However, a more pertinent question is maybe 'why?'  In general, one-time code generation is a bit of an anti-pattern.  What happens if you do a lot of this generation and then find a bug in the generator?  Now you've got to fix up all that generated code by hand.  I recommend you find a way to mesh your generated code with any handwritten elements that you need and keep the generator connected.

Comment: @GarethJ There are many reasons to generate code one-time. Starting a new project and using the template code is very similar to this. If I find a bug in the generator, I'll fix the generator.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do one-time code-generation with T4 then I would suggest using [T4 scaffolding](http://nuget.org/packages/T4Scaffolding). This tool was originally created to support the generation of views, controllers etc. in [MVC3](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) but you can use it on pretty much [anything](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/07/14/leverage-t4scaffolding-for-wcf-web-api.aspx).